# Get Count result of data in two tables join on same column sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, left-join

I have used the following code to Join two tables and count the number of servers. There are no issues with the code, all works fine but i wonder if there is any other way to write a clearer code. I will create a stored procedure using this query.

```
SELECT * FROM

    (SELECT 
        Count(*) AS ApiServerUsed, 
        (MaxLimit - Count(*)) AS ApiServerUnused, 
        MaxLimit as ApiServerTotal
    FROM [Client].[ClientSettings] LEFT JOIN [Setting].[Server] ON DockerApiHost = IpAddress
    WHERE Type = 1
    GROUP BY MaxLimit) s1,

    (SELECT 
        Count(*) AS GuiServerUsed, 
        (MaxLimit - Count(*)) AS GuiServerUnused, 
        MaxLimit as GuiServerTotal
    FROM [Client].[ClientSettings] LEFT JOIN [Setting].[Server] ON DockerGuiHost = IpAddress
    WHERE Type = 2
    GROUP BY MaxLimit) s2,
    
    (SELECT 
        Count(*) AS DbServerUsed, 
        (MaxLimit - Count(*)) AS DbServerUnused, 
        MaxLimit as DbServerTotal
    FROM [Client].[ClientSettings] LEFT JOIN [Setting].[Server] ON DbHost = IpAddress
    WHERE Type = 3
    GROUP BY MaxLimit) s3,

    (SELECT 
        Count(*) AS CacheServerUsed,
        (MaxLimit - Count(*)) AS CacheServerUnused,
        MaxLimit as CacheServerTotal
    FROM [Client].[ClientSettings] LEFT JOIN [Setting].[Server] ON CacheHost = IpAddress
    WHERE Type = 4
    GROUP BY MaxLimit) s4,

    (SELECT 
        Count(*) AS MqServerUsed,
        (MaxLimit - Count(*)) AS MqServerUnused,
        MaxLimit as MqServerTotal
    FROM [Client].[ClientSettings] LEFT JOIN [Setting].[Server] ON RabbitMQHost = IpAddress
    WHERE Type = 5
    GROUP BY MaxLimit) s5
```

Comment: yes this seems crazy you are cross-joining 3 sub-queries?

Comment: Why don't you simply add `Type` to your selected columns and the group by? Then you would only nee ONE query without the cross joining etc. and you COULD (if required) pivot the result in order to get the results side by side

Comment: the published query is used for the .net core project, TYPE is actually an enum which is stored in C# project. I thought if there is any way to use type in a dynamic way, so that i can avoid using sub-queries that much.